# How to fix EE 500 error, cannot use 'Bool' in Lexer.php?

Tags: php-errors

One of our websites http://mooseheadlakeedc.com is down, here's what our server technicians said about it:

> It appears that there is an issue with Expression Engine that is
>   causing a 500 error when loading the page. The error is:
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use
>   EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Library\Parser\Conditional\Token\Bool as
>   Bool because 'Bool' is a special class name in
>   /home/mooseheadlakeedc/public_html/system/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Library/Parser/Conditional/Lexer.php
>   on line 9
>
> Based on some Googling of the issue, it appears that this issue has
>   been resolved in newer versions of Expression Engine and updating it
>   should resolve the problem.

I'm new to expression engine and haven't developed on it before, and due to the error am unable to log into the back-end to perform the update. I also couldn't find the info on google he appears to have found. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this issue?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

first step would be to disable extentions via the config file.
this file is typically located at/system/expressionengine/config/config.php
change this line:

```
$config['allow_extensions'] = 'y';
```

to

```
$config['allow_extensions'] = 'n';
```

And try to log into the cp again

Comment: Thanks for your response Jelle. I tried that but was still unable get past the error and access the back-end.

Comment: I assume the site worked normally up to now?
it might also be that the server admins updated the php version. Can you change the php version to a lower one? Do you have access to the error log? more info could be found there

Comment: The site was working. Then we saved a Server Image of our server as a backup, and proceeded to upgrade our version of Apache, mySQL, and PHP. Then we saw that the site was down, so we reverted the server back to the backup/Server Image from before the upgrade, but the site is still down for some reason. The error log isn't showing errors on page load anymore - the last error was the one posted above in my question.

Comment: Is there a way to upgrade EE manually, without using the Update Wizard in the back-end?

Comment: I would revert the server updates first.
the site should come back up. then try to update EE and addons to the desired version. when tah's done and everything works update the server enviroment. 
the exact aproach depends a bit on what EE version you are on now, and what version you want to update to

Comment: Before I posted here, we did revert back to the backup, but the site is still having the error / not working.

Comment: are you really sure you are running on the exact same php/mysql/apache versions?

Comment: our server technician said that the server was restored to exactly as it was the moment the Server Image (backup) was taken, which was before we updated php/mysql/apache. So it should be exactly as it was before the updates.

Comment: that's strange, since that error indicates the server is running php7 and that's what's generating the errors. what if you upload a phpinfo file and access that directly?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, this was a bit of a mess, and the error I described above may not have been relevant to the environment of the site. That error came about after upgrading php/mysql/apache on the server, and since this site was down because of that, we reverted the entire server back to a Server Image Backup. So that error may not have been relevant to the state before the upgrades.

The original developer checked out the site and found that the .htaccess file and config were wrong, still not sure how, but that was where the issue ultimately was coming from.